# Rotating Matplotlib tick labels causes weird spacing issues

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following plot:

[image]

I would like to make the x-axis ticks more readable by rotating the ticks by ~40 degrees. So from:

`plt.xticks(list(range(0, width)), list(df_100.columns), rotation='90', fontsize=16)`

To:

`plt.xticks(list(range(0, width)), list(df_100.columns), rotation='40', fontsize=16)`

When I do this, though, I get some crazy spacing issues:

[image]

(ignore the change in color...)

What's causing this problem? How can I fix it? Here's a minimum working example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Z is your data set
N = 100
height = df_100.shape[0]
width = df_100.shape[1]
# Z = np.random.random((100, 29))

# G is a NxNx3 matrix
G = np.zeros((height,width,3))

# Where we set the RGB for each pixel
G[Z>0.5] = [1, 1, 1]
G[Z<0.5] = [0.25, 0.25, 0.25]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))
ax.imshow(G, interpolation='none')

ax.set_aspect('auto')
ax.grid(None)
ax.xaxis.tick_top()
plt.xticks(list(range(0, width)), list(df_100.columns), rotation='45', fontsize=16)
plt.yticks([0, df_100.shape[0] - 1], [1, df_100.shape[0]], fontsize=20)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: The images are not displayaed correctly, and there seems to be no colour change either...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If xticklabels are of the same length, you won't have this kind of problem. But given different length of labels, you can encounter this kind of problem. Because the default rotation is from the center of the xlabel string. So you can try to set the rotation anchor properly from 
['right', 'center', 'left'].

```
ha = 'left' # or 'right'. Experiment with it.
ax.set_xticks(x) # set tick location
ax.set_xticklabels(xlabels, rotation=40, ha=ha) # rotate the labels with proper anchoring.
```

Comment: This worked---thank you! Looks like `Left` is the proper setting - `right` causes even more problems. I'm guessing the rotation direction is the reason why.